# php REGEX help replace text inside of specific symbols

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with one being

```
[my_name] and another being <my_name>
```

I need to use a regex to search for any text within the [ ] and < > brackets and replace it with `BOB`

I would provide sample code but I don't even know where to begin. Any help would be appreciated

So far iv just tried this

```
  $regex = [\^[*\]]
```

thinking this will look for anything inside [] tags

Comment: Have you even tried to learn a bit about how to use Regex?

Comment: @Jerry Come on, chill. Such questions may be a challenge for some people. I find StackOverflow also as a great place to improve own skills.

Comment: @Jari If you don't know where to begin with regex, then you should, at the very least, try to learn *something*. SO questions that display some effort on the part of the OP are better received.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Of course, I agree with you 100%. But in fact, this question may be useful as well for other beginners.

Comment: Learn `regex` the nice way with [**regetron**](http://gitorious.org/regetron)

Comment: I have tried to look it over. Didn't really figure it out hence the reason im here

Comment: I dont get it if you dont wanna help then dont but dont post stupid things like have you ever tried it. I have tried it i just cant figure it out

Comment: @Yevo Can you show us what you've tried? It's not that we don't want to help, but as I mentioned before, on SO questions that show some effort on the part of the OP are received better.

Comment: sure i just added what im trying right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that the following should work:

```
preg_replace('/([\[<])[^\]>]+([\]>])/', "$1BOB$2", $str);
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
([\[<]) -> First capturing group. Here we describe the starting characters using
           a character class that contains [ and < (the [ is escaped as \[)
[^\]>]+ -> The stuff that comes between the [ and ] or the < and >. This is a
           character class that says we want any character other than a ] or >.
           The ] is escaped as \].
([\]>]) -> The second capturing group. We we describe the ending characters using
           another character class. This is similar to the first capturing group.
```

The replacement pattern uses backreferences to refer to the capturing groups. `$1` stands for the first capturing-group which can contain either a `[` or a `<`. The second capturing-group is represented by `$2`, which can contain either a `]` or a `>`.

Comment: I added the ending delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "[my_name] and another being <my_name>";
$replace = "BOB";

preg_replace('/([\[<])[^\]]*([\]>])/i', "$1".$replace."$2", $str);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. This replaces the whatever is matched with `BOB`.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use `preg_replace_callback` here is a quick example

```
$template = "Hello [your_name], from [my_name]";
$data = array(
    "your_name"=>"Yevo",
    "my_name"=>"Orangepill"
);

$func = function($matches) use ($data) {
    print_r($matches);
    return $data[$matches[1]];
};

echo preg_replace_callback('/[\[|<](.*)[\]\)]/U', $func, $template);
```

Comment: Why not modify your original answer instead of adding a new one?

Comment: I will delete the old... kept it around because I thought it might be useful for someone.